# simplemailer and yii framewoork

Tags: php, email, yii

I started working on yii framework in last 2-3 days....
i am trying to follow this tutorial [simple mailer](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/simplemailer) ....

After copying the files into extension folder and after writing these lines into configuration file, when I openned the index page of my test application, it gives me the following exception:

```
throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element.'));
```

and below is the screenshot of stacktrace:

[image]

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after copying the files into extension folder

You have to copy `simplemailer` into modules directory '/protected/modules/...

cp modules/SimpleMailer/commands/MailerCommand.php commands/

Execute installations:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/simplemailer#hh6

```
cd /your/app/directory/protected
./yiic migrate create add_simplemailer_tables
    --templateFile=application.modules.SimpleMailer.migrations.template
./yiic migrate up
cp modules/SimpleMailer/commands/MailerCommand.php commands/
```

Comment: thnx for your reply, i tried that but the output is still same as above

Comment: now it is showing me this error:    ( The table "sm_template" for active record class "SimpleMailerTemplate" cannot be found in the database. )

Comment: do i need to create table for e-mail template or you any other table

Comment: @sumitmann, if you did it, the table sm_template have to exists in database! But you have error: The table "sm_template" for active record class "SimpleMailerTemplate" cannot be found in the database.

Comment: @sergery, now i am having this error.....(Property "SimpleMailerTemplate.from" is not defined).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11825/discussion-between-sumitmann-and-sergey)